# Generating a data table to iterate through in a Django Template

Tags: django

I have this function that uses PrettyTables to gather information about the Virtual Machines owned by a user.  Right now, it only shows information and it works well.  I have a new idea where I want to add a button to a new column which allows the user to reboot the virutal machine.  I already know how to restart the virtual machines but what I'm struggling to figure out is the best way to create a dataset which i can iterate through and then create a HTML table.  I've done similar stuff with PHP/SQL in the past and it was straight forward.  I don't think I can iterate through PrettyTables so I'm wondering what is my best option?  Pretty tables does a very good job of making it simple to create the table (as you can see below).  I'm hoping to use another method, but also keep it very simple.  Basically, making it relational and easy to iterate through. Any other suggestions are welcome.  Thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["VM Name", "OS", "IP", "Power State"]
for uuid in virtual_machines:
  vm = search_index.FindByUuid(None, uuid, True, False)

  if vm.summary.guest.ipAddress == None:
    ip = "Unavailable"
  else:
    ip = vm.summary.guest.ipAddress

  if vm.summary.runtime.powerState == "poweredOff":
    power_state = "OFF"
  else:
    power_state = "ON"

  if vm.summary.guest.guestFullName == None:
    os = "Unavailable"
  else:
    os = vm.summary.guest.guestFullName

  x.add_row([vm.summary.config.name, os, ip, power_state])
table = x.get_html_string(attributes = {"class":"table table-striped"})
return table
```

Here is a sample of what it looks like and also what I plan to do with the button.  http://prntscr.com/nki3ci

Comment: Struggling to understand where the issue is here. You've already got a dataset you're iterating through (`virtual_machines`). Just add another column in `x.add_row`?

Comment: I am but since I'm using prettytables i dont need to iterate through it.  My question is more whats the best way to accomplish this so I can generate the HTML code while iternating through the data.  I was thinking of creating a dictionary but I feel that might be a little complicated.

Comment: The more I think about it, i would have to completely redo things.  I'm using template tags so parsing through the data as well wont be as simple to output back to the template.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to query the prettytable.  It was a minor addition without having to redo it all.

```
html = '<table class="table"><tr><th>VM Name</th><th>OS</th><th>IP</th><th>Power 
State</th></tr>'
htmlend = '</tr></table>'
body = ''
for vmm in x:
  vmm.border = False
  vmm.header = False
  vm_name = (vmm.get_string(fields=["VM Name"]))
  operating_system = (vmm.get_string(fields=["OS"]))
  ip_addr = ((vmm.get_string(fields=["IP"])))
  body += '<tr><td>'+ vm_name + '</td><td>' + operating_system + '</td> <td>'+ ip_addr +'</td> <td>ON</td></tr>'
html += body
html += htmlend
print(html)
```